# Update array element with same value of date key

Tags: php, arrays

Very thanks for your time. I am working on a PHP project where I want to update value of array. Let me show you example so you can understand it better.

**The first array look like**

```
array(30) {

      [10]=>
      array(2) {
        ["date"]=>
        string(6) "May 17"
        ["value"]=>
        int(0)
      }
      [11]=>
      array(2) {
        ["date"]=>
        string(6) "May 18"
        ["value"]=>
        int(0)
      }
      [13]=>
      array(2) {
        ["date"]=>
        string(6) "May 20"
        ["value"]=>
        int(0)
      }
      [14]=>
      array(2) {
        ["date"]=>
        string(6) "May 21"
        ["value"]=>
        int(0)
      }
}
```

**Second array look like**

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["date"]=>
    string(6) "May 17"
    ["value"]=>
    string(3) "821"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["date"]=>
    string(6) "May 17"
    ["value"]=>
    string(3) "822"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["date"]=>
    string(6) "May 21"
    ["value"]=>
    string(3) "830"
  }
}
```

Now all I want to replace the value of May 17 and May 21 in the first array. So it could look like

```
array(30) {

  [9]=>
  array(2) {
    ["date"]=>
    string(6) "May 16"
    ["value"]=>
    int(0)
  }
  [10]=>
  array(2) {
   ["date"]=>
    string(6) "May 17"
    ["value"]=>
    string(3) "821"
  }
  [11]=>
  array(2) {
    ["date"]=>
    string(6) "May 18"
    ["value"]=>
    int(0)
  }
  [12]=>
  array(2) {
    ["date"]=>
    string(6) "May 19"
    ["value"]=>
    int(0)
  }
  [13]=>
  array(2) {
    ["date"]=>
    string(6) "May 20"
    ["value"]=>
    int(0)
  }
  [14]=>
  array(2) {
     ["date"]=>
    string(6) "May 21"
    ["value"]=>
    string(3) "830"
  }
```

It would be great if I can show 2 instead of real value in May 17 because there is two occurance of May 17 in the second array.

Comment: You could make the array smaler in question. No need to list 27 items that don't change. Usually one or two items is enough.

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. 
You are expected to try to write the code yourself.
Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Hi @Andreas. I really sorry for that. Very thanks for the advice I have updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare the dates from both the arrays like the way shown below and add the desired values in if case.

```
 foreach ($array1 as $key => $value) {
        foreach ($array2 as $key2 => $arr) {
            if($value["date"] == $arr["date"]) {
                //add the desired values here like this, this will add the $arr['value'] to the first array
                $array1[$key]["value"] = $arr["value"]

            }
        }
    }
```

Hope it solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can iterate first array passing it in a foreach loop as a reference  and check for common values in second array as follows

```
  foreach($array1 as &$arr)
  {
        foreach ($array2 as $subarray) {
            if ($subarray['date'] == $arr['date'] ) {
            $arr['value'] = $subarray['value'];
            print_r("adsfg");
            }
        }
  }
```

you will get you the desired result.